# Hyperlink to doc file slow opening

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I've two excel file with inside some link to .doc and .pdf file. Both excel files and linked files are on a network shared folder. The first excel file is an .xls, the second an .xlsm.

While opening link to .pdf file is very fast (the file is open in few seconds) it take a long time to open .doc files (about 40 secs.). I have searched on internet but found no solution at the moment.

I have this problem with both excel 2007 and 2010.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot
Marco

Comment: With Word already opened it takes 38 seconds.. not 40 :)

Comment: I try to post my question on Server Fault! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can embed the .doc files rather than link them.  You'd lose updating from the source docs, but perhaps you'd eliminate the slow update of the linked content.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/link-or-embed-an-excel-worksheet-HA010120810.aspx (specifically "Insert a linked object or embedded object from an Excel file")

Comment: Linked files will be hundreds in a short time.. I prefer to not embed them. Thank you for your response!

Comment: I also want to benefice from updating files.. The link in my situation is the best solution! ..except for the opening latency.. maybe there is a workaround to speedup!!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to your startup add-in. I followed Srinivasu's answer from the link below and the hyperlink works instantaneously. I would imagine there is something built into your add-in. How to fix that I'm not sure.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/why-is-the-insert-hyperlink-dialog-taking-so-long/45cca6a5-4091-4c39-862e-3df164a7a8b0

Comment: Can you summarize the solution in the body of your answer in case the link goes bad?